# Gnuplot: Use fit in log scale

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, approximation

I need to make a linear approximation. However it needs to be in a log scale.

Here is my gnuplot script:

```
f(x)= a*x+b
fit f(x) "d0.dat" via a,b
set logscale x
set logscale y
plot "d0.dat" with points lt rgb "#ff0000" title "Points", \
f(x) with lines lt rgb "#ff00ff" title "Approximation"
```

[image]

Clearly the approximation is wrong. Can anyone help me to fix it. I didn't find any thing in google.

Comment: Please provide your d0.dat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnuplot is correctly fitting your data to the function you provided--a straight line.

The problem is that using a log scale for the y axis does not scale the data--just how the data are plotted.

Try fitting it to a power law:

```
f(x)= a*x**b
fit f(x) "d0.dat" via a,b
set logscale x
set logscale y
plot "d0.dat" with points lt rgb "#ff0000" title "Points", \
f(x) with lines lt rgb "#ff00ff" title "Approximation"
```

Answer (score 4):

I actually recommend a fit in logscale directly:

```
fl(x) = a+b*x
fit fl(x) 'data.dat'  u (log($1)):(log($2))  via a,b
replot exp(fl(log(x))) t 'log approx'
```

The difference is appreciable when (a few) values for large x are out of the fit. The cost-function is otherwise too strongly affected (because x and y are exponentially large).